# Game (Physics) work in Unity Editor/Remote but won't on Android?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection, unityscript

I have a script attached to a car game object that allows the player to tap the screen and then accelerate, the game object has a RB2D and collider set to it , it works fine in Unity Remote , but when I download the APK , as soon as I tap the screen , collisions go completely bezerk and the car just starts ignoring collisions , what's going on? As I need this to work to complete my game , as the player can move side to side with the accelerometer but I also want them to move forward when they touch the screen. Also , my game is 2D. Plus , since then , when the car ( my object) collides with anything else in the scene , it ignores it ( the obstacles just have Box Colliders on them). I had to freeze rotation so it could stop spinning out when it hit soemthing , now it just won't recognize collision at all. What's going on?
The code I think is causing the error starts at line 32. I have obstacles the player has to dodge and they all have box colliders and an appropiate script attached to them as well ( so when they collide with my player , it destroys it)

I've figured it out , Collision works when I first start the game , but when the player dies and I press "Replay" , it goes crazy. Here's the script that controls the enemy cars spawning , what the hell do I do to fix this?

```html
 Code (CSharp):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class EnemyCar : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed ;
public float acceleration = 0.5f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    speed += Time.deltaTime * acceleration;
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
 
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

I've done everything in the book trying to solve this , re-install unity , add different colliders etc. What's weirder is that it is FLAWLESS in Unity Remote and the Editor , these issues only arise when I test out the apk.

Here's how my game usually looks when the collisions work.
[image]

Now when it collides with a car ( on android) , it just ignores it and is slightly pushed back.

Help me!

Here is my script attached to enemy cars ( the cars that should destroy the player on Collision)

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyCar : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed ;
    public float acceleration = 0.5f;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        speed += Time.deltaTime * acceleration;

        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
  
 }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is the inspector view of my Player Car
[image]

[image]

Here is the inspector view of an enemy car ( they all have the same things)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

currentPlatformAndroid is misspelled right at the top of the file, inside the #IF.

Comment: Just changed it , still causes the error sadly.

Comment: I updated the code at the top of the post , it's the Replay button